# Codeigniter where query customisation

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

firstly I have the following details in my database table field as **'company_name'=>'Test Company'**.I want to return true after comparing the input data(either 'Test Company' or 'TestCompany') , because of the existence of that string (test company).Please suggest a query for finding the existence or non-existence.I have used the following,but it didn't works in all the scenarios.

```
$companyname="TestCompany";

$this->db->select("*"); 
    $companynames=str_replace(' ', '', $companyname);   
    $where = "company in ('$companyname','$companynames')" ;
            // $where = "'company' = $companyname OR 'company' = $companynames'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query=$this->db->get('users');
    $val= $query->result_array();
    if(empty($val)){ 
      echo '1';//non-existence  of 'TestCompany' and 'Test Company'
    }
    else {
     echo '2';//existence of 'TestCompany' or 'Test Company'
  }
```

The above code always prints '1' even if there is 'Test Company' exists in the database.

**Note**:The issue is when I select with 'TestCompany' the query will be like this

```
$where = "'company' = TestCompany OR 'company' = TestCompany'";
```

but the database contains 'Test Company' and the query returns no results.I want to solve this condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$companyNameTmp =  str_replace(' ', '', $companyname);
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE  REPLACE(`companyname`,' ','')='$companyNameTmp'
    ");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) >0)
{
    echo 'hi';
}
```

REPLACE doesn't work with active record so you have to do it in a normal mysql query. Rather than doing the OR Sudhir's solution of just removing the spaces from the incoming variable makes more sense. Then compare that to the database field with the spaces removed.

Comment: i will check and let you know.Thanks

Comment: Okay, just realized REPLACE doesn't work with active records, rewrote the query and that should work, I tested it on my DB.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like:

```
$companyname="Test Company";
$companyNameTmp = str_replace(' ', '', $companyname);   

$this->db->select("*"); 
$this->db->where('company_name', $companyname);
$this->db->or_where('company_name', $companyNameTmp); 
....
```

Or

```
$where = "company_name='$companyname' OR company_name='$companyNameTmp'";

$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: Thats because, you are using $companyname="TestCompany"; without spaces in between Test & Company, so str_replac()'ing it would result in same string.. shouldn't that be $companyname="Test Company"; with space in between..?

Comment: yes,I know that.But I have to track the match by using the string without spaces.